# Есть ли возможность изменить внешний вид gitlab (self-hosted)?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Есть ли возможность как-то поменять внешний вид gitlab в новой версии?
Теперь панель располагается слева и отнимает много места. Неудобно заводить issues, теперь картинки и скриншоты выглядят меньше.
Либо есть ли какие-то способы интегрировать gitlab в какую-нибудь систему постановки задач?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Внизу в левой панели есть клавиша "Collapse slidebar". Этот интерфейс был давным давно. Если что - можно менять `Settings->Preferences->Behavior->Layout width` и в разделе `Behavior` в опции `Layout width`. Возможно пример того какой "был" интерфейс - помогло бы ответить.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой сайт [userstyles.org](https://userstyles.org/styles/browse?search_terms=gitlab&type=false). Можно поискать нужную тему gitlab или сделать самому.

А есть другие сайты, например, [greasyfork.org](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/by-site/gitlab.com), где можно найти userscript-ы для gitlab и многих других сайтов.

Answer (score 0):

Внизу слева есть кнопка Collapse Sidebar - тык на нее и у тебя свернется эта панель